# JAVA StdDraw color as argument

Tags: java, colors, arguments, conditional-statements, stddraw

I have a little problem. I don't know if it's possible to have something like :

```
if(color from point (1, 1) == StdDraw.BLUE){[...]}
```

and if it is not possible, how can I put the color of a point as an argument in my condition ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Princeton Graphics library or utilities and so cannot answer this question, but you might wish to consider telling more details of your current problem, your current code, and also showing more pertinent code, anything that will help others to better understand your problem.

Comment: I'm working on a Pacman Game for studies ^^ and I work with StdDraw so I wanted to stop Pacman when he hurts a barreer. The barrers are blue so I wanted to detect when pacman's position +1 (x or y) is a point of a blue color.